# Xero Ruby SDK for OAuth 2.0 Request sending in tenantId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xero-api

We are trying to create a contact (applies to all requests) with the Xero Oauth 2.0 sdk gem.

When we make a request like this `xero_client.accounting_api.get_invoices(xero_client.last_connection['tenantId']).invoices`
The response we get is  `XeroRuby::ApiError: Error message: the server returns an error HTTP status code: 404`

However when we assign the tenantId first

`tenant_id = xero_client.last_connection['tenantId']`

and then make the request

`xero_client.accounting_api.get_invoices(tenant_id).invoices`
The client fetches all the invoices successfully.

Is anyone able to explain how this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a way to examine exactly what is being requested in the one that fails? Is there an issue with the URL that assigning your tenantId to another variable somehow fixes?